# Calculate an ellipse given Orbital Eccentricity and a Vertex from center point

Tags: c++, opengl, ellipse, orbital-mechanics

Calculating an elliptical orbit of a planet around the sun involves the formula:

e = c/a

where:

`c` is the distance from the center to a focus and

`a` is the distance from that focus to a vertex

How does one create a program to calculate this type of problem when elliptical shapes (namely in C++) do not use foci, but rather x and y max distances?

I currently have a function that creates an ellipse given an (x, y) center point and an x and y length.

I'm having issues converting a real elliptical orbit function `e= c/a` into a programs ellipse function `ellipse(x, y, xDistance, yDistance)`.

Is there a system out there for this or how would I go about accomplishing this? The intent is to draw a scale model of the planets' orbit around the Sun using actual data for each planet.

IE:
Mercury:

- 0.39 AU from the sun (distance)
- Orbital Eccentricity: 0.2056

Comment: "I'm having issues" --- please name them, or there's no question.

Comment: @n.m. I believe I listed the issue quite clearly. There are no foci in a typical programmatic ellipse calculation and all real world ellipses use them. Converting eccentricity into an xmax, ymax ellipse is the 'issue' at hand.

Comment: That's math, not programming. All relevant formulae are [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more precise:

Given a line `L`, called a *directrix*, a point `F` not on `L`, called a *focus*, and a positive number `e`. Let `d(X,L)` denote the distance from a point `X` to `L`, and let `|X|` denote the norm of `X`. The set `C` of points `X` satisfying

```
|X - F| = e d(X,L)
```

is called a *conic section* with *eccentricity* `e`. It is called an *ellipse* if `e < 1`, a *parabola* if `e = 1`, and a *hyperbola* if `e > 1`.

Now what you want is the *Cartesian equation* of the conic in *standard form*. If `e < 1` or `e > 1` and the directrix is parallel to the `y`-axis, the conic `C` is the set of points `X = (x,y)` satisfying

```
x^2 / a^2 + y^2 / [a^2 (1 - e^2)] = 1
```

where `a = e d / (1 - e^2)` and `d = d(F,L)` is the distance from the focus to the directrix.

If `e < 1` (so that `a > 0`), let `b = a sqrt(1 - e^2)`. We then obtain the equation of an ellipse in *standard form*

```
x^2 / a^2 + y^2 / b^2 = 1
```

where `a,b` are called the *semi-major* and *semi-minor axis* respectively. In this form,

- the ellipse center is at the origin `(0,0)`,
- the directrix crosses the `x`-axis at point `(d,0)`,
- the two foci are at points `(-c,0)`, `(c,0)` where `c = a e` and `c^2 = a^2 - b^2`,
- the two vertices on the `x`-axis are at points `(-a,0)`, `(a,0)`, and
- the two vertices on the `y`-axis are at points `(0,-b)`, `(0,b)`.

So your `a` is the distance from a `x`-vertex to the center and **not** to a focus. However, note that `c` is the distance from a `y`-vertex to a focus. This may be a source of confusion.

You can see that `a`, `b` are your missing `xDistance`, `yDistance`. It appears you are given `a` and `e`, so you only need to compute `b` as above.

Of course, you can always check [ellipse @wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse). [This figure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aEllipse_Properties_of_Directrix_and_String_Construction.svg) will help visualize my previous descriptions, but note that my `c` is denoted as `f` there.